# Get Total disk space mentioned in server manager

Tags: powershell

I need help in getting the **"Total disk space"** mentioned in server manager

[image]

I tried searching but I am not getting anything.

```
$total=0;Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume | ForEach-Object {$total += [Math]::Round((($_.Capacity - $_.FreeSpace) / 1GB),2)};Write-Output "TotalUsedSpace_GB : $total"
```

Please let me know how to get this value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(Get-Disk | measure-object -Property size -Sum).Sum / 1GB
```

or

```
(Get-Partition | measure-object -property size -Sum).Sum / 1GB
```

are both within ~500MB.

Comment: Thanks for your response. but when i ran  both the commands it is giving 2 different values
`
PS C:\Windows\system32> (Get-Partition | measure-object -property size -Sum).Sum / 1GB
327.2197265625

PS C:\Windows\system32> (Get-Disk | measure-object -Property size -Sum).Sum / 1GB
336
`